# How to prevent main thread from blocking when I am listening on bluetooth devices in a Xamarin Android app?

Tags: java, c#, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I have an app that I need to function as a bluetooth server, it will listen on incoming bluetoooth connections and print the message sent from those devices. I have managed to make some progress though I fear that I have might made a mistake calling a blocking method in the main thread of my app, that is the User Interface thread. When I call  `clientSocket= serverSocket.Accept();` everything in my app stops, i use a switcher to call the method that has the above line, the switcher shows like its turning on but hangs due to a method that imolements a blocking call till a bluetooth device connects to the socket. How can I avoid that effect on the main thread of my app because I believe once a bluetooth device connects to the app then the blocking call will be removed and the switcher will resume to being checked. I have thought about using a new thread to accept the socket but how will I display the data received from the device to a UI TextView element I have in my app since manipulation of TextViews and other UI is not allowed from a non-UI thread, Thank you

```
server_switch.Click += (o, e) =>
            {
                //check the check status of the switch and start and disable gatt accordingly
                Switch myswitch = o as Switch;
                if (myswitch.Checked)
                {
                    Log.Debug("Check Status Enabled", myswitch.Checked.ToString());
                    myswitch.Checked = true;
                    //switch the adapter mode and request for visibility
                    switch (_adapter.ScanMode)
                    {
                        case ScanMode.Connectable:
                            MakeVisibleFor300Seconds();
                            break;
                        case ScanMode.None:
                            MakeVisibleFor300Seconds();
                            break;
                        case ScanMode.ConnectableDiscoverable:
                                //do nothing, adapter in required mode
                                Log.Debug("Adapter Mode",
                                    "Connectable Discoverable:" +
                                    (_adapter.ScanMode == ScanMode.ConnectableDiscoverable).ToString());
                                break;
                    }
                      //create a new thread and run
                    
                    var newThread= new SocketListener(display_data, serverSocket);
                    newThread.Start();

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //the switch is disabled
                    Log.Debug("Check Status Enabled", myswitch.Checked.ToString());
                }
            };
```

***Class for accepting new connections***

```
  //create a new class for listening on connections and displaying message to the textview
    public class SocketListener : Thread
    {
        private TextView _data;
        private BluetoothServerSocket mysocket;

        private Stream output, input;
        //declare default ctor for reflections
        public SocketListener()
        {
            
        }
        //declare the custom ctor
        public SocketListener(TextView display, BluetoothServerSocket socket)
        {
            mysocket = socket;
            _data = display;
        }
        //override run and implement a blocking call
        public override void Run()
        {
            //NB: This implements a blocking call till a device connects
            BluetoothSocket source_device = mysocket.Accept();
            //get the input and output streams
            output = source_device.OutputStream;
            input = source_device.InputStream;
            //check if data is available and write it to our object
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input);
            string dat="";
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                dat += line;
            }

            _data.Text = dat;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You added `java` as a tag but the code looks like C#. If you are using Xamarin please add/correct your question.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, its android java interop on C#

Answer (score 1):

All the stuff about android, java, C#, xamarin, bluetooth, etc. is irrelevant. This question is essentially asking how to build a socket server application for a small number of clients, where "small" here means that you have the luxury of spawning one thread per client. (If you were to serve a large number of clients, then you would have to resort to a threadpool, but in your case that would be an unnecessary complication.)

The way we build a socket server application for a small number of clients is as follows:

1. One thread (the "Accept" thread) does nothing but an endless loop where it invokes `serverSocket.Accept()`.
2. When a socket connection is established, the "Accept" thread creates a "Session" thread for the connected socket. So, we have one "Session" thread per client.
3. Each "Session" thread receives packets from a client and sends packets back to the client. When a "Session" thread has something to useful to show to the user, the "Session" thread "posts" a message to the GUI thread, which means that it sends it in a thread-safe way. Different GUI systems support different means of accomplishing this; I am not sure about Xamarin, perhaps with `MessagingCenter.Send()`.

Comment: Hello sir from your reputation I can see you are advanced, I needed help with this, since the blocking call will not execute code below it as  it listens on connections forever, how to avoid that but still get the message from the source device?

Comment: As step 1 above says, this blocking call needs to be on a separate thread (the "Accept" thread) which does nothing but this blocking call and spawns other threads for clients.

Comment: I did extend the class and implemented the accept in the new class though am afraid it will not create sessions as per your advice, an answer in android java is welcome as I can convert it to C#, updating my code

Comment: There are lots of simple socket server examples out there on the interwebz for java, C#, C++, etc.

Comment: Yeah I will take a look and see if I can find something I can use